# Some Device not getting READ_PHONE_STATE permission like; Redmi, Oppo

Tags: java, android, call

Some Devices like; Redmi, Oppo is not getting READ_PHONE_STATE_PERMISSION.
Moto is getting properly. But I want to know why some devices not getting this permission.
I am using receiver.

Comment: I am using READ_PHONE_STATE_PERMISSION for getting IMSI in my Mi phone (Oreo) and its working fine, so can u explain bit  better

Comment: I am using READ_PHONE_STATE_PERMISSION for getting Call Logs. @vikassingh

Comment: now as per google policy u can not read call log  only defauly app for call and sms has the permission to read call log and introduce new call group permission for  that.      https://proandroiddev.com/no-more-sms-call-log-permissions-now-what-9b8226de7827